# Cant create new directory inside existing directory in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

Im using IntelliJ community version for Spring project, and I have issue with creating new directory named **images** inside already existing directory **resources -> static**. When I right click on static and I add new directory **images**, instead of creating new directory this is created.

[image]

Someone could say that it is ok, this is a way new directory is shown, but I dont think that is correct. When I try to remove **images** directory I can remove only both directories **static.images** directory. If I try to add new directory into **static** directory, it goes into **static.images**  and not into **static**.

[image]

So question is how to create directory inside another directory? There is no issue when I add new package inside another package in the **src->main->java** project structure.

Comment: Please disable "Compact Middle Packages" option under grey cog wheel in Project Tree.

Answer (score 0):

The other person is correct. The directory was created as you desired, it is just displayed differently that you expected.

To verify this, open a shell and list the directories. The following shows all the directories under the current directory.

```sh
$ find . -type d
```

The directory parent is based on where in the path you click. If you click on the word `static` you will create a directory under the `static` directory. If you click on the word `images` you will create a directory under the `images` directory.

Comment: Project structure when opened in the terminal shows that image dir being created. However that doesnt address the issue that that directory is not shown as a separate dir from static dir and I cant create directory inside of static. 
When I right click in IDE in the project structure on  static.images  dir with intention of creating new_directory inside if static, the new directory is created but inside images dir. I want to create new dir inside of static dir.

Comment: I added more info at the end of my answer.